# what's the meaning of VOID() in C

Tags: c, semantics, void

what's the meaning of `VOID()`

There are the following C code, but what's it's meaning?

```
VOID(pthread_mutex_init(&tina_mutex,MY_MUTEX_INIT_FAST));
```

Comment: It's almost certainly a macro - did you try searching for it ?

Comment: coming from mysql sources? A quick search gives: " `#define VOID(x) x`
The intention is to avoid lint warnings about ignored return value of some functions like printf()"...don't know if that helps you out?

Comment: It's an abomination. Remove it, and if you're the boss, fire whoever introduced it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a preprocessor macro. Your editor should be able to find what it is. Or try

```
gcc -E source.c > source2.c
```

It runs the preprocessor only and replaces macros with what they really evaluate to.

Answer (score 4):

pthread_mutex_init returns 0 on success or an error value. I think the macro you have just casts this result to void, thereby convincing the compiler that it shouldn't emit a warning about ignoring the return value..